# .this en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quería hacer una consulta respecto al funcionamiento de .this en javascript, estoy leyendo un articulo el cual trata sobre la utilización de este método.
Les adjunto el link que lleva a este articulo:
[Articulo .this javascript](http://www.etnassoft.com/2012/01/12/el-valor-de-this-en-javascript-como-manejarlo-correctamente/)

el código que por el momento no estoy logrando comprender es el siguiente:

```js
var myApp = function(){
  var that = this; // Work around!
  var name = "World"
  var sayHello = function(){
    console.log( 'Hello, ' + that.name );
  };
 
  sayHello();
};
 
myApp(); // Hello, World
```

No entiendo como llega a obtener Hello, World , ya eh intentado de varias formas y no logro que arroje ese resultado, lo estoy probando en codepen pero en vez de decir "Hello, World" me arroja "Hello, codepen!" es algo confuso. Gracias.

Comment: de hecho si lo ejecutas no imprime Hello World

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this

Comment: El artículo que estás usando de guía es de Enero del 2012, en 7 años la programación cambia bastante. Te recomiendo que uses documentación más actualizada o podrías estar aprendiendo métodos que ya ni siquiera existen o han caído en desuso.

Comment: No logras comprender el código porque es incomprensible. En el contexto de tu código `this` representa a la ventana. En otros contextos, `this` puede representar el elemento sobre el que se hizo click (un botón por ejemplo), el evento que lanza una acción, etc. En el caso que muestras `this` sería útil para mostrar algo sobre la ventana: `console.log(this.document.charset);` pero para tu *Hello World*, lo **comprensible** es esto: `console.log( 'Hello, ' + name );` porque `this.name` o `that.name` que es lo mismo, obtienen el nombre de la ventana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Investigando un poco vi que `this` hace referencia al objeto window
[image: se puede ver el objeto this]

Cuando llamas `that.name`, lo que haces es llamar name del objeto `window`, por eso ati te sale codepen i aqui sale de otra cosa cuando lo ejecutas.

Aqui te dejo resultado en la maquina local y editores online:

1. MAQUINA LOCAL: [image: LOCAL] (si, name es WORLD, pero del objeto window)
2. REPL.IT:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. AQUI MISMO: `Hello, 7c21d1d2-80c5-97f4-7078-8bc2e011b34d`

Si quieres que tu codigo funcione mira eso

```js
var myApp = function () {
    var sayHello = function () {
        var that = this; // Work around!
        this.name = "Wordsyuitfld"
        console.log('Hello, ' + that.name);
    };
    sayHello();
};
myApp(); // Hello, World
```

Asi le dejas claro el `this.name`